# What is the equivalent of the following jdk path in Ubuntu 8.04?

Tags: ubuntu, java, ubuntu-8.04

I got to setup the following two variables:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/i386/:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/i386/client/:./
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0/
```

Since, the above is for the version of JDK installed via SunJDK, what could be the equivalent path for the `openjdk-6-jdk` package?

My OpenJDK is installed at:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
```

I couldn't find the folder `i386/`, though. To which path should I point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `open-jdk` package itself does is not distributed with any shared objects/libraries (`.so` files) on Hardy, although `open-jre` does.

Normally you need not set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` manually, as the `java` binaries should automatically seek any standard `open-jre` libraries at their well-known locations.  If, however, you are encountering issues with library dependencies (see how to use the `ldd` command to identify such unmet dependencies, below), you *may* need to point `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to either `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/` (IIRC Slicehost's architecture is AMD 64bit) or `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/`.

Also export `JAVA_HOME` as `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk`

You may confirm that `java` satisfies all shared objects/libraries dependencies by running:

```
ldd $JAVA_HOME/bin/java
```

For a complete list of the files distributed as part of `open-jdk` and `open-jre`, see [the open-jdk (amd64) file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/amd64/openjdk-6-jdk/filelist) and [the open-jre (amd64) file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/amd64/openjdk-6-jre/filelist), or run:

```
dpkg -L openjdk-6-jdk
dpkg -L openjdk-6-jre
```

...on your system.